# Does Java API of Rocks DB support prefix scan?

Tags: java, rocksdb

I have huge data set(key-value) in Rocks DB and I have to search for key based on prefix of key in hand. I do not want to scan whole data set to filter out key based on key-prefix. is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use something like this.
Using RocksIterator there is a api exposed where you can seek to the key substring and if your key starts with the prefix then consider that key.

Please find the sample code.

```
List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
RocksIterator iterator = db.newIterator();
for (iterator.seek(prefix.getBytes()); iterator.isValid(); iterator
                .next()) {
           String key = new String(iterator.key());
            if (!key.startsWith(prefix))
            break;
      result.add(String.format("%s", new String(iterator.key())));
}
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of [@Pramatha V](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3901432/pramatha-v) works pretty well, although I made some improvements to the code. I am not deserializing the iterator key in every iteration. I am using the `Bytes.increment()` from the [Kafka common utils](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/common/utils/Bytes.java) (you can extract this class and use it in your code directly). This function increments the underlying byte array by adding 1. With this approach, I can find the next bigger key than my prefix key. I am using the `BYTES_LEXICO_COMPARATOR` (also from the same class) to make the comparison, but you are free to implement and use your comparator. Moreover, the function returns a map of byte arrays, which you can deserialize later in your code.

```
public Map<byte[], byte[]> prefixScan(final byte[] prefix) {
    final Map<byte[], byte[]> result = new HashMap<>();
    RocksIterator iterator = db.newIterator();

    byte[] rawLastKey = increment(prefix);
    for (iterator.seek(prefix); iterator.isValid(); iterator.next()) {

        if (Bytes.BYTES_LEXICO_COMPARATOR.compare(iterator.key(), rawLastKey) > 0
                || Bytes.BYTES_LEXICO_COMPARATOR.compare(iterator.key(), rawLastKey) == 0) {
            break;
        }

        result.put(iterator.key(), iterator.value());
    }

    iterator.close();
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Seek is working very slow.   5.35 Seconds on SSD disk , 1 billion records.

The size of the Keys are fixed 16 bytes.  Searched for 8 bytes.

2 Long bytes [xx,xx]

Searched for 1 Long as 8 bytes.

Use ColumnFamily  for  mapping keys.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it